# Windows 7 - IIS 7.5 showing blank

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7.5

I have installed IIS 7.5 and restarted the machine but when I open the IIS, its showing blank and can not create websites under it.. tried Googling for a solution but couldn't find any help.. Please advice how to solve this..
[image]

Comment: Do you have sufficient privileges on the machine?  Check you're in the local Administrators group as a starter.

Comment: Have you installed any of the IIS features. Go to "Programs and Features" -> "Turn Windows Features on of off", "Internet Information Services" -> "Web Management Tools" and make sure IIS Management Console and IIS Management SErvice are checked.